# Creating selectable "block" from selected group

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, eaglecad

I have several connectors on some PCB in [Eagle PCB Editor](https://www.autodesk.com/products/eagle/features#pcb-layout-editor) and I've placed connector pins description table to every of it and for instance, let's take a look at connector J5, which is highlighted at the moment:
[image: Highlighted J5 Connector]
Now, the table has been created using [WIRE](http://web.mit.edu/xavid/arch/i386_rhel4/help/100.htm) and [TEXT](http://web.mit.edu/xavid/arch/i386_rhel4/help/93.htm) commands, applied to layer `21 - tPlace`. Now, the problem is, if I, for instance, want to [MOVE](http://web.mit.edu/xavid/arch/i386_rhel4/help/61.htm) the table somewhere else, I have to use command [GROUP](http://web.mit.edu/xavid/arch/i386_rhel4/help/49.htm) and select it segment by segment:
[image: J5 Connector table segmented select]
and I can `move`, `rotate` od do whatever I want with it. Now, is it possible to create some kind of object from selected table so I can avoid segmented selection in future?

Comment: Unfortunately, Eagle doesn't have persistent groups aside from library components. It's on their wishlist though. Until then – create a component for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the answer you wanted (since Eagle does not support defined group) but here's a workaround I use.

I put that stuff on the tDocu or bDocu layer. Then I can temporarily turn of tPlace and other layers so I can select it easily by just dragging a box around it. This makes moving tables and other documentation easier.

The danger is forgetting to include tDocu and bDocu in the silkscreen when generating gerbers so I make sure to use my own CAM processing file where I've already included those layers.